# onChangeText returns the previous state value

Tags: react-native, use-effect, use-state

I am trying to make a dynamic form. The user must enter the required **count** of fields in the first text field. After that, I add the entered **count** to the state and render all the fields. But in "onChangeText" the **previous state** value is returned. At the same time, if I click on the button, the **current state** value is returned?

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {Button, TextInput, View, StyleSheet} from "react-native";

export const TestScreen = () => {
    const initialState: any = {
        num: null,
        inputs: null
    };
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

    const changeNum = (num = null) => {
        const inputs = [];
        if (num) {
            for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                inputs.push(
                    <TextInput
                        key={i.toString()}
                        style={styles.input}
                        onChangeText={changeNewInput}
                    />
                )
            }
        }
        setState({num, inputs})
    };

    const changeNewInput = (e) => {
        console.log(state.num)
    };

    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput onChangeText={changeNum} style={{...styles.input, borderColor: 'red'}}/>
            {state.inputs}
            <Button title={'see count'} onPress={() => console.log(state.num)}/>
        </View>
    )
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    input: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'black',
        marginBottom: 5
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

the state update using the updater provided by useState hook is asynchronous. That's why you see previous value of your state when you call changeNewInput method after setState. If you want to see your state is updated you can use, useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(state.num)
}, [state]);
```

Comment: But how do I get an updated state in an onChangeText callback?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using my code example

Create a new useEffect and set a new State inside

```
OLD STATE const [comment, setComment] = useState('')
NEW STATE const [newData, setNewData] = useState(null)

onChangeText={text => setComment(text)}


useEffect(() => {
    setNewData(comment)
},[comment])
```